# Tag cleanup request: [vps]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The [vps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vps) tag is a mess. Please help me clean it up, ideally by generous application of close votes.

The vast majority of questions I see under this tag are about using a VPS (virtual private server) in general, or about installing, configuring, or running software on such a server. For example:

- [why my vps doesn't show me static ip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33488636/why-my-vps-doesnt-show-me-static-ip)
- [error installing casperjs on linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159294/error-installing-casperjs-on-linux-server)
- [How to login to VPS contaier via SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35392971/how-to-login-to-vps-contaier-via-ssh)

None of these questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow, as they are (at best!) about using and deploying software, not about developing it. Some of these questions may belong on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), depending on the question and the environment the user is working in, but most should probably just be closed entirely.

A few of these questions are on-topic questions about developing software that runs on a VPS. The fact that it's running on a VPS is almost always irrelevant to the question, so the tag adds no value here; please remove it in these cases.

(A *vanishingly small* number of questions might actually have to do with writing software to implement or manage VPS environments. These are fine; leave them alone.)

Comment: When someone casted a bunch of close votes on these feel free to leave a *please filter on `[tag:vps]` in the CVQ* message in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and some of our regulars will do their part.